# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "saeta" como canto religioso?

Tags: etimología, españa, religión, música

Estamos en Semana Santa y estos días en España es común oír hablar de las *saetas*. Esto es, *un canto religioso tradicional interpretado fundamentalmente en las procesiones de Semana Santa en España, especialmente en Andalucía y algunas zonas de Extremadura, Castilla La Mancha y Murcia*.

Así nos lo define la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saeta_(m%C3%BAsica)) y, un poco antes, explica que la palabra viene de *sagita*, flecha en latín. Efectivamente, el DRAE así lo indica:

> [**saeta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WyM29TD)
>   Del lat. *sagitta*.
>   1. f. flecha (‖ arma arrojadiza).
>   2. f. Aguja del reloj.
>   3. f. En una brújula, flecha que se vuelve hacia el polo magnético.
>   4. f. Punta del sarmiento que queda en la cepa cuando se poda.
>   **5. f. Palo flamenco consistente en una jaculatoria o copla que una persona dedica a las imágenes de las procesiones.**

Antes de nada, esto me hace ver que [Sagitario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitario_(astrolog%C3%ADa)) tiene el mismo origen y que por eso su símbolo es una flecha. También, que algo [*sagital*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wz2J8v5) es el que tiene forma de flecha y que al futbolista Alfredo Di Stéfano [se le llamaba *La Saeta Rubia* por ser rápido como una flecha](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-alfredo-di-stefano-era-conocido-como-la-saeta-rubia/).

Volviendo a la Semana Santa, me pregunto: ¿qué relación hay entre el canto religioso y las flechas para que use este nombre? ¿Tendrá sentido la siguiente cita (extraída del artículo de la Wikipedia también) del siglo XIX de Antonio Machado Álvarez para definirlas o es un mero juego de palabras para llegar donde quería llegar?

> cancioncillas que tienen por principal objeto traer a la memoria del pueblo, especialmente en los días del Jueves y Viernes Santos, algunos pasajes de la pasión y muerte de Jesucristo (...) coplas disparadas a modo de **flechazos** contra el empedernido corazón de los fieles.

Comment: Podría ser debido a algún símbolo religioso? Algún tipo de vara que termine en punta de flecha o similar que se use mediante las procesiones? Según wiktionario además, la saeta es un canto **improvisado y sin acompañamiento** y dice "[...] tiene su origen en el folclore andaluz"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando en el NTLLE encuentro que en el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1739) se recoge la siguiente definición para *saeta*:

> Por alusión se toma por el objeto que hace impresión en el ánimo, como hiriendo en él.

Aunque por aquel entonces no se recogía la acepción del cante, ya se entendía *saeta* de modo alegórico. En 1803 se recoge además la siguiente acepción:

> Cada una de aquellas coplillas sentenciosas y morales que suelen decir los misioneros, y que también suelen decir durante la oración mental.

Se nota claramente que el significado alegórico evolucionó y se denominó así a estas coplillas que, al parecer, trataban de zaherir morales. Es curioso que estas acepciones se hayan perdido en la versión actual. Sin embargo, en esta misma versión de 1803 aparece también la siguiente construcción:

> ECHAR SAETAS. Mostrar alguno con palabras, gestos o acciones que está picado o sentido de alguna cosa.

No queda del todo claro si la expresión "echar saetas" surgió antes o después de las coplillas de los misioneros. En todo caso, en la versión de 1817 del diccionario a la definición de las coplillas de los misioneros añade lo siguiente:

> [...] y en las demandas nocturnas que hacen en Madrid los hermanos de la Esperanza.

Ya tenemos hasta el lugar de origen (y por una vez no es Andalucía). En 1843 se actualiza esta última parte de la definición por:

> [...] y en otros actos de devoción y penitencia.

No fue hasta 1899 cuando la definición cambió por una ya más parecida a la actual:

> Coplilla breve y sentenciosa que, para excitar a la devoción o la penitencia, se canta en las iglesias o en las calles durante ciertas solemnidades religiosas.

En 1936 pasa de "coplilla" a "copla". En 1956 se añade como sinónimo de "jaculatoria" ("oración breve y fervorosa"), y en 1970 se amplía esta definición como:

> Jaculatoria o copla que una persona canta en las procesiones.

Hasta 2001 estas dos definiciones iban por separado, hasta que en la última versión se fusionaron (o se perdió la de la coplilla sentenciosa) para quedar en la siguiente forma:

> Palo flamenco consistente en una jaculatoria o copla que una persona dedica a las imágenes de las procesiones.

Resumiendo, todo se basa en la imagen alegórica de las flechas como elementos que inciden en el alma, moral, ánimo lo que sea de cada uno, provocando una impresión o reacción.

Comment: La respuesta de su pregunta sobre tener duende y este fue en una de mis libros sobre el historia del flamenco, así como todos los tipos de palos y las aportaciones de los gypsies.  Lo he borrado, después de leerlo y ahora no puedo encontrarlo en mis copias de seguridad. Yo hubiera podido contestar dos preguntas en una...

Comment: Fantástica investigación que culmina en un _Resumiendo_ como colofón. ¡Gracias! Y ahora, a correr a escuchar saetas, que tú las tienes cerca :)

Comment: @fedorqui quita, quita, mejor que vaya a escucharlas quien pueda apreciarlas, yo soy un sevillano atípico... :-D

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente, y a pesar de lo que afirma la RAE, soy de la misma opinion de algunos flamencologos que la Saeta viene del arabe Shahadah, ٱلشَّهَادَةُ o la proclamacin de la fe.  Cualquier turista educado puede ver que cuando Curro Albayzín esta cantando una saeta él esta haciendo exactamente lo mismo que un almuédano cuando canta un adhan أَذَان‎ .  Shahad' (suena al oido espanol como "sha-jad" con un sonido despues de la "d" expirada como "de" que se convertio en "Sahed'e" y finalmente en Saeta.  Una flecha no tiene ningun sentido y no hace falta torcer el coco para que "flecha" tenga sentido ya que el flamenco esta lleno de palabras del arabe y el ebreo (jaleo=jalel; farruca=farruk, etc).